# What's going on with Logitech options?

Tags: logitech-mouse

My "Logitech Options" app won't start. Shows me a black screen.

[image: black screen]

Comment: @John Windows 10. I already reinstalled, but it didn't help

Comment: try https://www.reddit.com/r/LogitechG/comments/cw5ke9/cannot_get_logitech_options_software_to_work_on/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thank you all guys, but I found solution by myself.For those who have the same problem, I advise to install version [8.34.82](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-us/articles/360025297893) and then update app. Maybe it doesn't work on Mac, but its work on Windows 10!

Comment: Please have a look at [Can I answer my own question?](https://superuser.com/help/self-answer) and come back two days later and check as answered if you have more than 15 reputation.

Answer (score 2):

This should be the exact error. The answer below is from Logitech support.

```
Faulting application name: LogiOptionsMgr.exe, version: 8.54.161.0, time stamp: 0x60c0f109
Faulting module name: LogiOptionsMgr.exe, version: 8.54.161.0, time stamp: 0x60c0f109
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x0000000000865b80
Faulting process id: 0x5d44
Faulting application start time: 0x01d794502b6152f3
Faulting application path: C:\ProgramData\Logishrd\LogiOptions\Software\Current\LogiOptionsMgr.exe
Faulting module path: C:\ProgramData\Logishrd\LogiOptions\Software\Current\LogiOptionsMgr.exe
Report Id: b41c519a-5ca0-4d30-ab6e-b0a8b40c9396
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:

Fault bucket 1731130740225525218, type 5
Event Name: BEX64
Response: Not available
Cab Id: 0
------------------------------------------------------------
Problem signature:
P1: LogiOptionsMgr.exe
P2: 8.54.161.0
P3: 60c0f109
P4: LogiOptionsMgr.exe
P5: 8.54.161.0
P6: 60c0f109
P7: 0000000000865b80
P8: c0000409
P9: 0000000000000007
```

ANSWER

• Open "Add or Remove Programs" and remove Logitech Options, if present.

• Cleanup temporary files

- Open the Windows app Delete Temporary Files
- Click option Temporary file
- Wait a moment until the scanning as completed
- Make sure there are NO checkmark in Downloads
- Now click Remove files
- Wait for the purging progress to complete, this may take a few minutes depending on how many temporary files needs to be cleaned up

• You need to enable hidden files and folders, by doing the following steps:

- Open File Explorer
- Select the tab View
- Click the icon Options to open the Folder Options window
- Select the View tab and in Advanced settings list find and select "Show hidden files, folders, and drives"
- Click the button OK

• Removing remnant files, if present

- Open the Run window (Windows + R)
- Type %appdata% and click OK
- This should open File Explorer
- Navigate to folder Logishrd
- Delete the folder LogiOptions
- Close the File Explorer
- Open the Run window (Windows + R)
- Type %programdata% and click OK
- This should open File Explorer
- Navigate to folder Logishrd
- Delete the folder LogiOptions
- Close the File Explorer
- Open the Run window (Windows + R)
- Copy and paste this path C:\Windows\System32\DriverStore\FileRepository\unifhid.inf_amd64_3994342584154151\x64
- Click OK
- Delete two files

> LdaCx2.dll
> LogiLDA.DLL

- Now close the File Explorer
- Open the Run window (Windows + R)
- Copy and paste this path C:\Windows\System32\
- Click OK
- Delete the file

> LogiLDA.DLL

- Now close the File Explorer

• Removing remnant Windows Registry entries, if present

- Open the Run window (Windows + R)
- Type regedit.exe and click OK
- This should open Registry Explorer
- Navigate to folder Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\
- Delete the folder LogiOptions
- Close the Registry Explorer

• Restart your computer

• Download and install all available Windows updates

• Download and install the latest version of Logitech Options from https://support.logi.com/hc/articles/360025297893

If the issue persist,

- Try re-installing the latest .NET framework.
- Try to install all the necessary updates for the OS of your computer.
- Re-install the Microsoft Visual C++ (64bit).
- Re-install DirectX drivers.

-If same issue - please perform a full clean wipe again and reinstall in Safe mode
-Check if will have the same behavior on another computer

Answer (score 1):

I too began experiencing this issue on my system running Windows 8.1 after experiencing a BSOD. Reinstalling Logitech Options ([v8.54.161 - Last for Win7/8.1](https://support.logi.com/hc/en-ca/articles/360025297893)) didn't make any difference, nor did deleting my logitech options configuration files.

What I immediately noticed to have fixed it was running the Logitech Bluetooth Service:

[image: Logitech Options Bluetooth Service (Not Running)]

While troubleshooting, I noticed the above service was the only Logitech service in the Windows Services Management Console, and it wasn't *Running*, as can be seen above. Upon *Starting* the service, and relaunching Logitech Options, everything was back to normal. To start the service, do as follows:

1. Press `Win` + `R` on your keyboard to open the "Run" dialog.
2. Type in `Services.msc` into the "Run" dialog and hit `Enter` to open the Windows "Services" Management Console.
3. Click anywhere in the Services list and start typing out "Logitech Bluetooth Service" on your keyboard to automatically select it.
4. Click "Start" in the left panel to run the service.
5. Now launch Logitech Options and it should load as it normally used to with all your configurations intact.

Hope that helps.

Comment: maybe your answer help someone os I'll give you 1 voice :D

Answer (score 0):

Durring installation selecting "Do not send debug data" helped to fix this issue in my case.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://superuser.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://superuser.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1120507)